# Limits at negative infinity

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that $\lim_{x\to -\infty}$ $\frac{x}{x+2}$ = 1.

Please help me check if this is correct:

> > Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given. Choose $M=2-\frac{2}{\varepsilon}$
> >
> > $$\begin{align}
> >   x<M \Rightarrow x-2 < M-2\\
> >   \frac{1}{x-2} > \frac{1}{M-2}\\
> >   |f(x)-1|=|\frac{x}{x-2}-1|=|\frac{2}{x-2}|\\
> >   <|\frac{2}{M-2}|=\frac{-2}{M-2}=\varepsilon
> >   \end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $x \to -\infty$, we may assume $M < 0$.  Then your line $\frac{1}{x-2} > \frac{1}{M-2}$ is a relationship between two negative quantities.  Thus $\left|\frac{1}{x-2}\right| < \left|\frac{1}{M-2}\right|$.  Can you take it from there?

Comment: Yes. Thank you.

Comment: Is the value for M same as when x goes to positive infinity?

Comment: $M$ is not a fixed value.  It depends on $\epsilon$, as in:  "Let $\epsilon >0$ be given.  Then there is a number M..."

Comment: As a follow up, you may always restrict $M$ based on what you are trying to prove.  When $x \to -\infty$, it makes sense to restrict $M < 0$.  The reason is that we want to argue about what happens when $x$ gets arbitrarily negative, so of course $x$ should eventually be less than a negative number!